# RequiredFieldValidator still validates when hidden

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have 2 fields that I need to validate, if they are displayed on the screen.  When the Form initially loads, they are hidden and they will stay hidden unless an item is selected from a DropDown box.  Once the value is selected, the 2 fields appear and then the validation is working correctly.  However, if another value is selected that doesn't make these 2 fields appear, they are still being validated and not allowing the page to submit.  Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```
function DisplayOutageDates() {
    if ($('#ddImpact').val() == "Service Affecting") { 
    $('#outageDates').css('display',''); 
    document.getElementById('txtOutageStartDate').Visible = true;
    document.getElementById('RFVOutageStartDate').Visible = true;
    } else {
    $('#outageDates').css('display','none');
    document.getElementById('txtOutageStartDate').Visible = false;
    document.getElementById('RFVOutageStartDate').Visible = false;
    }
}

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVOutageStartDate" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtOutageStartDate" SetFocusOnError="true"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter the Outage Start Date" />
```

Comment: How do you validate those fields ?

Comment: You need to show the code/script related to your validation process.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
ValidatorEnable(val, enable): 
Takes a client-validator and a Boolean value. 
Enables or disables a client validator. 
Being disabled will stop it from evaluating and it will always appear valid.
```

Found on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside).

Using Javascript this would look like:

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=Validator1.ClientID%>'), state);
//where state would be a boolean
```

In JQuery this would look like:

```
 ValidatorEnable($("#<%= Validator1.ClientID %>")[0], state);
```

As found here: 
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-manage-asp.net-validation-from-javascript-with-jquery.aspx

Comment: The `<%=` wont work.  Give me a compilation error.  But, it still didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to show and hide the `Validator` controls as showing and hiding the input controls.

---

**Update**

If you hide the `Validator` controls using `display:none;` They still get rendered and involved in the validation process. You need to hide them by setting the `Visible` property to *false*. This way they won't get rendered neither involved in the validation process.